# If five geometric means are inserted between 8 and 5832, what is the fifth term in the geometric series?

Tags: arithmetic, word-problem

If five geometric means are inserted between 8 and 5832, what is the fifth term in the geometric series?

Again i don't understand the wording of the problem.

So in general: what does it mean for $n$ means to be inserted between $a$ and $b$, and in particular when those means are geometric?

Comment: I think it means that $$8,a_2,a_3,a_4,a_5,a_6,5832$$ is geometric series. Find $a_5$.

Comment: @OfirSchnabel that's what i was asking, so please edit your answer to include that so that i can accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think its means that
$$8,a_2,a_3,a_4,a_5,a_6,5832$$
is a geometric series. Find $a_5$.

Then,
$$8\cdot x^6=5832.$$
Then $x^6=729$ and $x=3$.

Therefore, $$a_5=8\cdot 3^4=648.$$

Comment: Happy to help :)

Answer (score 1):

Take the $6$th root of $\frac{5832}{8}$, which turns out to be $3$.

So, the sequence is $8$,$24$,$72$,$216$,$648$,$1944$,$5832$

A series is geometric, if $\frac{a_{k+1}}{a_k}=q$ for all $k\ge 1$.

In other words, to get the next member of the sequence, you must multiply the actual one with some constant number $q$.

Comment: i don't want an answer, just an explanation of the wording, thanks anyway

Comment: i know that, by the way you made a mistake what if $a_k=0$ for some $k\ge1$, i upvoted btw

Comment: I do not know if the $0$-sequence is considered to be a geometric sequence.

Comment: okay thanks ! ! : )